# Is there a way to pass user inputs that I am already taking for my script as arguments for a cron job?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I need to run the same test as a cron job where I need to compare the results with the previous test. Please let me know how can I achieve this. Thank you

I have written a script to perform ping test for few routers. As the test is done before, after maintenance window I am taking the input from user as pre and post and comparing the results after post test is done.

```
input("please enter pre or post")
if pre or post:
    #some action
if post:
    #compare pre and post results which are already saved as individual files
```

pre- "SUCCESS RATE IS 0 PERCENT", post- "SUCCESS RATE IS 0 PERCENT" -PASS

pre- "SUCCESS RATE IS 0 PERCENT", post- "SUCCESS RATE IS 20 PERCENT" -FAIL

Comment: Cron jobs are meant to run in the background and don't have any user input mechanism as far as I know.

Comment: @Trinopoty Please let me know how can I compare the result with the previous one every time i perform the test as a cron job. Also let me know if there is a way to find if the script is being executed manually or as a cron job.

Comment: For detecting if script was called from cron, you can add a flag like `--cron` to the cron table and check that in your program.